# How to clone rust library, change it and then use it in my own project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to clone the `tokio` library and make a few changes to it, then use it in another project, just like I would if I had specified `tokio` as a dependency in my `Cargo.toml`.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [path dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies) for this.  Paths are interpreted as relative to the `Cargo.toml` they appear in, so you have a few options:

Have your tokio fork as a subdirectory `tokio` in your project, or symlinked there:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { path = "tokio" }
```

Have your tokio fork live somewhere else in your home directory:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { path = "/home/youruser/tokio-fork" }
```

Or wherever else makes the most sense for you.

Comment: I found [this link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html#testing-a-bugfix) in related questions, it answered it all.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, if instead of local dev, you want to use git, you could fork the repo an use reference it:

```
tokio = { git = "https://github.com/your-user/tokio" }
```

Take a look at the [documentation on how to specify dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html)